# C# Use type of object for casting (to avoid use of switch case)?

Tags: c#, types, casting

I got an abstract Room with multiple child classes. Some of those childs have a property `MaximumCapacity`. When anything enters a room, I want it to check if that Room has the property, and if so, what it is. I could easily make it using a switch case, but I'd rather not (lots of (repetitive) code).

Only two imporant properties:

- `MaximumCapacity`: Maximum capacity of the Room, stored in **some** of the different type of rooms
- `CurrentPosition`: Room stored on the object that wants to enter the Room.

This is what I currently have:

```
// HOW :: Store type of Room in order for me to cast with it.
// My Attempt: 
Type T = CurrentPosition.GetType(); // Get the type of the Room

// The following doesn't work:
// Build-time exception: "T is used as a variable but is a type"
if ((CurrentPosition as T).GetProperty("Capacity") != null) 
{
    // Check capacity and enter Room.
}
```

I've tried doing the `if (int.Parse(CurrentPosition.GetType().GetProperty("MaximumCapacity")) > [number])` But this gives a `Can't convert type PropertyInfo to Int`. This makes me believe I still have to cast the Room to its clild (I think) in order to check the capacity.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have an `IHasCapacity` interface. Those classes with that property should implement the interface. Then use `is IHasCapacity` or `as IHasCapacity`.

Comment: If you really want to stick with your current approach, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2 .

Comment: `GetProperty` return property, but not property value. You should call `GetValue` on property to get its value.

Comment: You can have nullable value type and check it's HasValue property in child classes. In this way, you can skip the use of reflection.

Comment: As others proposing you can also use interface with a max capacity to check whether you are implementing that property or not, and based upon it you can perform your logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for an `interface` and *Composition*. This way you can check if your rooms support your various functionality

**Given**

```
public interface IMaximumCapacity
{
   int MaximumCapacity { get; set; }
}

public class BaseRoom
{

}

public class DerivedRoom : BaseRoom, IMaximumCapacity
{
   public int MaximumCapacity { get; set; }
}
```

**Method**

```
public static bool GetMaximumCapacity(BaseRoom room, out int maximumCapacity)
{
   maximumCapacity = 0;

   if (room is IMaximumCapacity capcityRoom)
   {
      maximumCapacity = capcityRoom.MaximumCapacity;
      return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

**Usage**

```
if(GetMaximumCapacity(someRoom,out var max)
{
    // yay, do something with max
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without type checking.
Change type of `MaxCapacity` to nullable and make all rooms to have this property.
Then you can simply does room have value of maximum capacity

```
if (room.MaxCapacity.HasValue)
{
    // do you logic
}
```

You can do it in more object-oriented way, move logic to the room object to decide is somebody allowed to enter a room

```
if (room.AllowedFor(player))
{
    // do your logic
}
```

Then rooms which have MaxCapacity will check for that, rooms which hasn't will always return false.

Answer (score -1):

```
public abstract class Room
{
    public abstract void BookTheRoom();
}
interface IMaximumCapacity
{
    int MaximumCapacity { get; set; }
}
public class StorageRoom : Room
{
    public override void BookTheRoom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Storage room booked to store the items.");
    }
}

public class TwinSharingRoom : Room,IMaximumCapacity
{
    public TwinSharingRoom(int capacity)
    {
        MaximumCapacity = capacity;
    }

    public int MaximumCapacity { get; set; }

    public override void BookTheRoom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Twinsharing room booked.");
    }
}

public class SingleSharingRoom : Room, IMaximumCapacity
{
    public SingleSharingRoom(int capacity)
    {
        MaximumCapacity = capacity;
    }

    public int MaximumCapacity { get; set; }

    public override void BookTheRoom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Single sharing room booked.");
    }
}
```

And you can use this as

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listOfRooms = new List<Room>() { new SingleSharingRoom(1), new StorageRoom(), new TwinSharingRoom(2) };

        foreach(var room in listOfRooms)
        {
            if(room is IMaximumCapacity)
            {
                room.BookTheRoom();
            }
        }
    }
}
```